# How use Artboard and Nestedartboard from Rive in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation, rive

I want to use a rive animation like this one

> https://rive.app/community/1514-2958-flower-composition-tutorial/

I notice that this artboard contains a somes NestedArtboard this nested artboard are not loaded by my app, I would like to know why this happen?

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';

class RiveBackground extends StatefulWidget {
  const RiveBackground({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RiveBackground> createState() => _RiveBackgroundState();
}

class _RiveBackgroundState extends State<RiveBackground> {
  // Declarations necessary to rive
  final riveFileName = 'assets/rive/last.riv';
  Artboard? globalArtboard;

  // Animation controller
  late RiveAnimationController _animationController;

  // Loads a Rive file
  Future<void> _loadRiveFile() async {
    final bytes = await rootBundle.load(riveFileName);
    RiveFile rFile = RiveFile.import(bytes);

    final artboard = rFile.artboardByName('Motion');

    print(globalArtboard);
    globalArtboard = artboard!
      ..addController(
        _animationController = SimpleAnimation('Animation 1'),
      );
    setState(() {});
  }
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _loadRiveFile());

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building');
    return Scaffold(
      body: globalArtboard != null
          ? Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Rive(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                artboard: globalArtboard!,
              ),
            )
          : const Center(child: Text('empty')),
    );
  }
}
```

**Expected result**
[image]

**My result**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you found a solution for this already, but according to [this response](https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/issues/193#issuecomment-1158134343) in [this Github issue](https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/issues/193),

> to get the nested artboard to show through, you should instance the Artboard when you set it up with the Rive widget, so your setup would go from:

```
Rive(artboard: riveFile.artboardByName("artboard"));
```

> to

```
Rive(artboard: riveFile.artboardByName("artboard")!.instance());
```

more detail in the link. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks i resolve the problem some time ago. Thanks for the reply.